# Did the United States ever impose any trade embargoes on the basis of health related concerns?

Tags: 20th-century, trade

Did the United States (particularly in the 20th century) ever impose any trade embargoes on the basis of health related concerns? Are there instances where the U.S. said that if Country X doesn't meet particular health standards, it will limit trade with said country?

Comment: Can you clarify "health related concerns?"?

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by "embargo" and "limit trade". A general embargo on trade is an extreme measure, generally used for geo-political, not health concerns. For example the USA's policies today regarding Cuba and Iran. OTOH, we have numerous instances of the USA restricting imports of certain products based on health concerns - China has been the focus of much recent activity because of concerns about lead and other toxic substances in their products. Please clarify.

Answer (score 5):

**Yes,** there is at least one example below.

As of June 21, 2011, the US had partial trade embargoes, issued by the CDC, on the import of birds from the following countries due to the H5N1 virus (bird flu):

**East Asia and the Pacific:**

- Myanmar
- Cambodia
- China
- Hong Kong
- Indonesia
- Japan
- Laos
- Malaysia
- South Korea
- Thailand
- Vietnam

**South Asia:**

- Afghanistan
- Bangladesh
- India
- Kazakhstan
- Nepal
- Pakistan

**Europe & Eurasia:**

- Albania
- Azerbaijan
- Romania
- Russia
- Turkey
- Ukraine

**Africa:**

- Benin
- Burkina Faso
- Cameroon
- Djibouti
- Egypt
- Ghana
- Ivory Coast (Cote d’Ivoire)
- Niger
- Nigeria
- South Africa
- Sudan
- Togo

**Near East:**

- Iran
- Iraq
- Israel
- Jordan
- Kuwait
- Palestinian Autonomous Territories
- Saudi Arabia

These have since been rescinded.

According to Princeton WordNet, a trade embargo is a government order restricting international trade. Wikipedia says that such embargoes can be partial embargoes, such as Princeton WordNet's [import barrier](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&s=import+barrier). A country may choose what and how many items are excluded in a partial trade embargo. In the above case, the partial trade embargo restricts just the import of birds into the US.

---

**Sources:**

- [Embargo of Birds from Specified Southeast Asian Countries - CDC](http://www.cdc.gov/flu/avian/outbreaks/embargo.htm)
- [Trade embargo - Princeton WordNet](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=trade%20embargo)
- [Embargo - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embargo)

Comment: For the record, [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=cT1BOgQ2Ys8C&pg=PA11382&dq=%22cuba+trade+embargo%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=02qdVfPuG8Tw-AHPg4CYBQ&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22cuba%20trade%20embargo%22&f=false) is how Congress refers to the Cuba embargo.

Answer (score 2):

No, there are no instances of "Country X does not meet health standards" leading the United States to stop trade with that country.

There are however plenty of cases when the United States (and also other countries) have stopped imports of particular products from particular because of health concerns. Countries where there are outbreak of "mad cow disease" will typically see other countries shutting down import of beef, as an example.

Comment: _"No, there are no instances ..."_: You did not find any or you found a source that said there were no instnaces?

Comment: @EugeneSeidel: You are asking for proof of non-existence. Those are impossible.

Comment: No, I am not asking for "proof of non-existence", I'm asking for the basis for your confidently made statement that _"there are no instances"_.

Comment: @EugeneSeidel: The confidence comes out of the lack of any such instances to be found, combined with the utter absurdity of such a trade embargo. "Because the chicken from Farfaraway is a health risk we will forbid imports of Farfarawayan steel". Admittedly I have not found any reliable source listing what they claim to be a complete list of US trade embargoes, but even so, that would not be proof.

Comment: @LennartRegebro There are conceivable situations were the idea is not so patently absurd. For example, suppose there were a disease in Country X that was transmitted by rodents, and this had become such a problem in Country X that all trade with Country X presented a significant risk of bringing infected rodents back to the US. Then, a trade embargo might be reasonable.

Comment: @LennartRegebro - I had to downvote - EugeneSeidel is very correct. I said essentially the same thing in my comment on the question, but declined from making it an answer because I had no good sources. You are making an assertion about concrete facts, with no substantiation whatsoever.

Comment: @EugeneSeidel - I agree with you. IMO this answer is sorely deficient.

Comment: @called2voyage: No, then an embargo on travel and shipping would be reasonable. That's not a trade embargo.

Comment: @LennartRegebro Travel and shipping embargoes are subsets of trade embargoes. Trade embargoes need not be full embargoes where *all* commerce is forbidden, but can be partial embargoes.

Comment: @called2voyage No. A trade embargo forbids *trade* with a country, ie buying or selling things to and from that country. It does not forbid ships stopping in the country’s ports, not does it forbid people to travel there. They are subtypes of *embargoes*, yes. But the question is specifically about **trade** embargos.

Comment: @LennartRegebro I'm not confusing blockades and embargoes. "Embargo" in the sense of travel and shipping is shorthand for "trade embargo".

Comment: @LennartRegebro Travel and shipping is a form of commerce.

Comment: @LennartRegebro For example, the US trade embargo against Cuba forbids travel and shipping. This is considered a part of the trade embargo.

Comment: @called2voyage: No "embargo" is not shorthand for "trade embargo". http://www.thefreedictionary.com/embargo http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/embargo#English http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/embargo The question is explicit about *trade*, not travel restrictions or shipping, but *trade*. Your attempt to shoehorn your "conceivable" situation into the question is silly. If you can find an example of a full trade embargo based on health concerns you prove me wrong, but every comment in which you don't serves no further purpose.

Comment: @LennartRegebro You directly ignored my example of the Cuba trade embargo. I will no longer continue this discussion with you.

Comment: @called2voyage: The embargo against cuba is generally called "embargo" not "trade embargo". This is easily verified with a simple Google search. [32 million hits](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=cuba+%22trade+embargo%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#channel=fs&q=cuba+embargo+-%22trade+embargo%22) vs [390.000 hits](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=cuba+%22trade+embargo%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#channel=fs&q=cuba+%22trade+embargo%22) Yes, please stop this discussion, it's pointless.